# gestehen vs. zugeben

Tags: difference

Soweit ich weiß, haben "gestehen" und "zugeben" im juristischen Kontext die gleiche Bedeutung. "Gestehen" kann auch ohne Akkusativobjekt benutzt werden.

> Der Angeklagte hat **gestanden**.
>
> Der Angeklagte hat das Verbrechen **gestanden** / **zugegeben**.

Aber wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen diesen Verben?

Wenn wir etwas machen, was nicht strafbar ist, aber trotzdem sozusagen gegen Moral oder Ethik (lügen, betrügen, jemandem etwas Übles antun) verstößt, kann man dann sowohl "gestehen" als auch "zugeben" verwenden?

> Sie hat **gestanden** oder **zugegeben**, dass sie dich belogen hat.

Und was ist mit der Meinungsäußerung?

> z.B. Ich muss **gestehen** oder **zugeben**, dass diese Aufgabe schwierig ist.
>
> z.B. Ich muss **gestehen** oder **zugeben**, dass dein Musikgeschmack schrecklich ist.
>
> z.B. Du musst **gestehen** oder **zugeben**, dass sie eine sehr nette Person ist. (Vielleicht ist dieser Satz nicht Meinungsäußerung, sondern eher: Bitte stimme mir zu!)

---

> Ich muss **gestehen** oder **zugeben**, dass ich diese Verben immer
> verwechsle.

Letztendlich nehme ich an, es gibt feste Ausdrücke, die nur zu einem Verb passen.

- jemandem seine Liebe gestehen
- jemandem Untreue gestehen
- die Wahrheit gestehen

Comment: Hätte er vorher nicht gestanden, hätte er nachher nicht zu sitzen brauchen.

Comment: Du kannst nicht gestehen oder zugeben, dass der Geschmack des Angesprochenen schrecklich sei. Du kannst gestehen, dass Du ihn schrecklich findest, weil das Empfinden zu Dir gehört, aber der Geschmack des Anderen gehört zu ihm, daher könnte er, dass sein Geschmack schrecklich ist, nur selbst gestehen/zugeben.

Comment: Kann man das Folgende sagen - "Du musst gestehen / zugeben, dass sein Musikgeschmack schrecklich ist."?

Answer (score 7):

They are pretty much interchangeable, and people will always know what you mean whichever word you choose. However, there are a few subtle difference, because „zugeben“ usually means that you admit something you were confronted with, while „gestehen“ means you confess something, which can be out of the blue.

And you are right, in your example „Du musst gestehen oder zugeben, dass sie sehr nette Person ist.„ you can use „zugeben“ to indicate that you are looking for agreement. This is another subtle difference: „du musst zugeben“ often means „you have to agree/admit, that...“ while „ich muss gestehen“ often is an admission of guilt. If you are explaining to your mother why you failed a test, you could say „du musst zugeben, der Test war schwierig“ oder „ich muss gestehen/zugeben, ich habe zu wenig gelernt.“

A notable exception is when you confess someone your feelings, „ich muss dir etwas gestehen“ or „ich habe ihm meine Gefühle gestanden“ are common phrases, while „zugeben“ doesn’t work (unless, as I mentioned in the beginning, someone accused you of your feelings and you maybe even denied it, but now admit it - then zugeben would be fine.)

Comment: We also have "zugestehen" to mean "admit". But I don't know any subtle meaning difference.